# GTest: fixture required when TYPE_TESTING global functions?

Tags: unit-testing, googletest

I want to unit-test some global templated functions using `TYPED_TEST`. The following code works, I just wonder whether there is way I can get rid of the test fixture, as it does not seem to be needed..

```
#include <gtest/gtest.h>
#include <base/mathfunctions.h>

template <class T>
class MinTest : public testing::Test {};

// The list of types we want to test.
typedef ::testing::Types<int, float> Implementations;

TYPED_TEST_CASE(MinTest, Implementations);

TYPED_TEST(MinTest, ReturnsMinimumValue) 
{
   EXPECT_EQ(Base::Min<TypeParam>(-5, 5), -5);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ... as it does not seem to be needed

It is needed. See this self-contained simplification of your unit-test source
(it makes nonsense of the name `ReturnsMinimumValue`, but that doesn't matter):

**gtester.cpp**

```
#include <gtest/gtest.h>

template<typename T>
struct foo {
    static T bar() {
        return 0;
    }
};

template <class T>
class MinTest : public testing::Test {};

typedef ::testing::Types<int, float> Implementations;

TYPED_TEST_CASE(MinTest, Implementations);

TYPED_TEST(MinTest, ReturnsMinimumValue)
{
    EXPECT_EQ(foo<TypeParam>::bar(),0);
}
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    ::testing::InitGoogleTest(&argc, argv);
    return RUN_ALL_TESTS();
}
```

Compile, link and run that:

```
$ g++ -Wall -Wextra -o gtester gtester.cpp -lgtest -pthread && ./gtester
[==========] Running 2 tests from 2 test cases.
[----------] Global test environment set-up.
[----------] 1 test from MinTest/0, where TypeParam = int
[ RUN      ] MinTest/0.ReturnsMinimumValue
[       OK ] MinTest/0.ReturnsMinimumValue (0 ms)
[----------] 1 test from MinTest/0 (0 ms total)

[----------] 1 test from MinTest/1, where TypeParam = float
[ RUN      ] MinTest/1.ReturnsMinimumValue
[       OK ] MinTest/1.ReturnsMinimumValue (0 ms)
[----------] 1 test from MinTest/1 (0 ms total)

[----------] Global test environment tear-down
[==========] 2 tests from 2 test cases ran. (0 ms total)
[  PASSED  ] 2 tests.
```

Now let's preprocess the source file, and prettify the preprocessed output (because it's not pretty):

```
$ g++ -E -P gtester.cpp | clang-format > gtester.ii
```

Look at the the last 50-odd lines of the output:

**gtester.ii**

```
...
...
int RUN_ALL_TESTS() __attribute__((warn_unused_result));
inline int RUN_ALL_TESTS() { return ::testing::UnitTest::GetInstance()->Run(); }
template <typename T> struct foo {
  static T bar() { return 0; }
};
template <class T> class MinTest : public testing::Test {};
typedef ::testing::Types<int, float> Implementations;
typedef ::testing::internal::TypeList<Implementations>::type
    gtest_type_params_MinTest_;
template <typename gtest_TypeParam_>
class MinTest_ReturnsMinimumValue_Test : public MinTest<gtest_TypeParam_> {
private:
  typedef MinTest<gtest_TypeParam_> TestFixture;
  typedef gtest_TypeParam_ TypeParam;
  virtual void TestBody();
};
bool gtest_MinTest_ReturnsMinimumValue_registered_ __attribute__((unused)) =
    ::testing::internal::TypeParameterizedTest<
        MinTest,
        ::testing::internal::TemplateSel<MinTest_ReturnsMinimumValue_Test>,
        gtest_type_params_MinTest_>::Register("",
                                              ::testing::internal::CodeLocation(
                                                  "gtester.cpp", 17),
                                              "MinTest", "ReturnsMinimumValue",
                                              0);
template <typename gtest_TypeParam_>
void MinTest_ReturnsMinimumValue_Test<gtest_TypeParam_>::TestBody() {
  switch (0)
  case 0:
  default:
    if (const ::testing::AssertionResult gtest_ar =
            (::testing::internal::EqHelper<(
                 sizeof(::testing::internal::IsNullLiteralHelper(
                     foo<TypeParam>::bar())) ==
                 1)>::Compare("foo<TypeParam>::bar()", "0",
                              foo<TypeParam>::bar(), 0)))
      ;
    else
      ::testing::internal::AssertHelper(
          ::testing::TestPartResult::kNonFatalFailure, "gtester.cpp", 19,
          gtest_ar.failure_message()) = ::testing::Message();
}
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  ::testing::InitGoogleTest(&argc, argv);
  return RUN_ALL_TESTS();
}
```

Our:

```
TYPED_TEST(MinTest, ReturnsMinimumValue)
{
    EXPECT_EQ(foo<TypeParam>::bar(),0);
}
```

expands to the definition of:

```
template <typename gtest_TypeParam_>
class MinTest_ReturnsMinimumValue_Test;
```

which is derived from the template fixture:

```
template <class T> class MinTest;
```

which is derived from:

```
testing::Test;
```

from which `MinTest_ReturnsMinimumValue_Test` inherits:

```
virtual void TestBody();
```

and overrides it as:

```
void MinTest_ReturnsMinimumValue_Test<gtest_TypeParam_>::TestBody() {
  switch (0)
  case 0:
  default:
    if (const ::testing::AssertionResult gtest_ar =
            (::testing::internal::EqHelper<(
                 sizeof(::testing::internal::IsNullLiteralHelper(
                     foo<TypeParam>::bar())) ==
                 1)>::Compare("foo<TypeParam>::bar()", "0",
                              foo<TypeParam>::bar(), 0)))
      ;
    else
      ::testing::internal::AssertHelper(
          ::testing::TestPartResult::kNonFatalFailure, "gtester.cpp", 19,
          gtest_ar.failure_message()) = ::testing::Message();
}
```

which implements the expansion of:

```
EXPECT_EQ(foo<TypeParam>::bar(),0);
```

A different test framework might accomplish type-parameterised test cases
differently, but this is how googletest does it.

The polymorphic class hierarchy:

```
template <typename gtest_TypeParam_>
class MinTest_ReturnsMinimumValue_Test
    <-
template <class T> class MinTest
    <-
testing::Test
```

is not generated because of any presumption the method call(s) under test
are polymorphic. `foo<TypeParam>::bar()`, of course, is not. The polymorphic
class hierarchy is generated because such is the basic design of googletest.